# Fast batch saving of photos to camera roll

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, alassetslibrary

As we all know, saving a photo, be it `UIImage` or raw `NSData` to iOS' Camera Roll takes some amount of time. But I have gone even further and not only do I save the photo to the Camera Roll, I then move it to the designated `ALAssetGroup`:

```
[assetsLibrary writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:img
                                          orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)image.imageOrientation
                                   completionBlock:^(NSURL* assetURL, NSError* error) {
if (error.code == 0) {
         NSLog(@"saved image completed:\nurl: %@", assetURL);
         // try to get the asset
         [assetsLibrary assetForURL:assetURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
         // assign the photo to the album
         [[groups objectAtIndex:page] addAsset:asset];
```

I'm calling this method on a background thread but it still takes very considerate amount of time to complete - about 3 - 4 seconds.

What I need is I want to get as closest as possible to the default iOS camera behavior of "batch-shooting" - when the image is saved **immediately** after it has been taken, and then the next one, and the next one and the next one.

How should I approach this? Using `NSOpertaionQueue` might be an option but will it be considerably faster?

Any decisions working on iOS 6 and up are highly appreciated

Comment: If you're calling it on a background thread, why is it blocking your interface? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @CarlVeazey it's not quite blocking it - it takes around 40 megabytes of memory and it *eventually* results in some minor lags, that's the case.

Comment: What kind of device are you using to test your App. Yes, taking picures and saving them takes a lot of resources — that's why apple has implemented this feature only in the latest devices.

Comment: If it is lagging, when you are doing stuff in background thread — it probably means that you are consuming 100% of CPU. If you want to underatand the reason of it — try not to save photos at all, just take them and don't store anywhere. If it gets faster, you can try to store them in memory — don't save them to disk, just store them in an NSArray. Is it still fast? In this manner you will get the reason of lags — camera, memory operations or disc operations. You can also try to use Apple's Profiler it's in built-in Instruments — it will show you the place that consumes most CPU.

Comment: I understand that three comments in a row is just too much, but... How do you create you background thread? `[self performSelectorInBackground thread]`? I would suggest using `(void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector onThread:(NSThread *)thr withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait` with `[NSThread setThreadPriority:(double)priority]` — with a lowest priority, so saving would not affect CPU usage. If you want an illusion of photos appearing immediately — you can save low-quality copies first, and then replace them with the real photos.